# BlueSky Statistics Hanging

Tags: statistics

When I try to start BlueSky Statistics, sometimes the application hangs and the "Starting BlueSky Statistics" box remains on the screen.   I see the app open in the background, but the loading box remains and I must use the task manager to be able to use anything.

Answer (score 0):

BlueSky Statistics is hanging because you have 2 instances of the application running. You can have only 1 instance running at any time. Use the task manager to kill the extra instance.